# How to completely remove/uninstall ps3mediaserver from Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall

I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove ps3mediaserver
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get purge ps3mediaserver
```

I also rebooted the system several times.

However, `ps3mediaserver` is still broadcasting as a DLNA server and is being seen by every device in the house.  This is really frustrating.

Comment: `sysctl stop ps3mediaserver` ?

Comment: i tried that but i get the error that "stop is an unknown key"

Comment: `sysctl disable ps3mediaserver` then?

Comment: Did `apt-get` claim to have removed `ps3mediaserver`? I don't understand how it could still be running after rebooting if it was actually removed.

Comment: apt-get never returned any errors.  but i started thinking about it, and rebooted the router, and apparently something got hung up there because it was gone after the reboot.